# Calling Javascript function defined in external file through PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a web page on which i have a simple login form consisting of username and password text fields.

I validate the login form using `javascript` external file and if `javascript` code returns `true`, login form is submitted otherwise an error message is displayed via `javascript` function named `displayErrorBlock()` that i wrote.

If the form is submitted then using `PHP`, i verify username and password. If username/password combination is incorrect or doesn't exists in database, **i want to call** the same `javascript` function `(displayErrorBLock)` from `PHP` code.

To do this, i echo this

```
else { // if username/password combination is incorrect
     echo '<script>displayErrorBlock("Incorrect Username/Password")</script>';
}
```

**but** this gives me `displayErrorBLock undefined` error because `javascript` is loaded at the end of the `body` tag of my web page.

#### Question

**How can i call** `javascript` function `(displayErrorBlock)` that is defined in an external file ?

This is the `displayErrorBlock` function defined in an external `js` file

```
function displayErrorBlock(errorMsg) {
    'use strict';
    let errorBlock = document.querySelector('.error-msg-block');
    errorBlock.style.display = 'block';
    errorBlock.firstElementChild.textContent = errorMsg;

    setTimeout(function () {
        errorBlock.style.height = '48px';
    }, 10);
}
```

## Edit

Here my entire web page

```
<?php

    require 'DbConnection.php';

    // if login button is clicked
    if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username-field'];
        $password = $_POST['password-field'];

        verifyLoginCredentials($username, $password);
    }

    // verify admin login credentials
    function verifyLoginCredentials($username, $password) {
        global $dbConnect;
        $query = 'SELECT full_name, username, password FROM admins WHERE username = ?';
        $statement = $dbConnect->prepare($query);

        if($statement) {
            $statement->bind_param('s', $username);
            $statement->execute();
            $resultSet = $statement->get_result();

            // since there will be only one row returned at max, no need of a loop
            $row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc();

            if($row != null) {
                $adminFullName = $row['full_name'];
                $adminUsername = $row['username'];
                $adminPassword = $row['password'];

                // if username/password is correct start session and store
                // username, password, full name in the session and login
                // admin to his account
                if($username === $adminUsername && password_verify($password, $adminPassword)) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['current_admin_fullname'] = $adminFullName;
                    $_SESSION['current_admin_username'] = $adminUsername;
                    $_SESSION['current_admin_password'] = $adminPassword;

                    //take current admin to admin dashboard
                    header('Location:admin dashboard.php');
                }
                else { // if username/password combination is incorrect
                    echo '<script>displayErrorBlock("Incorrect Username/Password")</script>';
                }
            } else { // if username doesn't exists in the database
                echo '<script>displayErrorBlock("Entered Username isn\'t registered")</script>';
            }
        }

    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Resources/Bootstrap v4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/admin login.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/common.css"/>
    <title>Admin Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 navbar-container">
          <nav class="top-navbar">
            <img src="../Resources/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
            <p>Admin Panel</p>
          </nav><!--end of navbar-->
        </div><!--end of first column-->
      </div><!--end of first row-->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 login-form-container">

          <p class="error-msg-block">
            <span></span>
          </p>

          <form class="login-form" method="post" action="admin login.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <p>Welcome Back!</p>

            <div class="form-group username-group">
              <label for="username-field">Username</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <img src="../Resources/images/envelope.png" alt="envelope image"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" id="username-field" type="text" name="username-field" id="username-field" placeholder="Username"/>
              </div>
            </div><!--end of first form group-->

            <div class="form-group password-group">
              <label for="password-field">Password</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <img src="../Resources/images/lock.png" alt="lock image"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" id="password-field" type="password" name="password-field" id="password-field" placeholder="Password"/>
              </div>
            </div><!--end of second form-group-->

            <input type="submit" class="btn" id="login-btn" name="login-btn" value="Login"/>
          </form><!--end of login form-->

        </div><!--end of first column-->
      </div><!--end of second row-->

    </div><!--end of container-->

    <!--CDN versions of JQuery and Popper.js-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../Resources/Bootstrap v4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Javascript/admin login form validation.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Updated Question

I am facing a couple of problems.

1. I am getting whole web page as a response when i try to log to log `.responseText` to console inside `.onLoad` method.
2. When form is submitted via ajax, main `if statement` in php file

   `if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])) {....}`

   never evaluates to true, hence php code isn't executing.

What am i doing wrong here?

Here's my php code

```
<?php

    require 'DbConnection.php';

    // if login button is clicked
    if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username-field'];
        $password = $_POST['password-field'];
        echo '<script>alert(\'form submitted\')</script>';   <---- this alert is never invoked
        verifyLoginCredentials($username, $password);
    }

    // verify admin login credentials
    function verifyLoginCredentials($username, $password) {
        global $dbConnect;
        $query = 'SELECT full_name, username, password FROM admins WHERE username = ?';
        $statement = $dbConnect->prepare($query);

        if($statement) {
            $statement->bind_param('s', $username);
            $statement->execute();
            $resultSet = $statement->get_result();

            // since there will be only one row returned at max, no need of a loop
            $row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc();

            if($row != null) {
                $adminFullName = $row['full_name'];
                $adminUsername = $row['username'];
                $adminPassword = $row['password'];

                // if username/password is correct start session and store
                // username, password, full name in the session
                if($username === $adminUsername && password_verify($password, $adminPassword)) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['current_admin_fullname'] = $adminFullName;
                    $_SESSION['current_admin_username'] = $adminUsername;
                    $_SESSION['current_admin_password'] = $adminPassword;
                }
                else { // if username/password combination is incorrect
                    echo 'Incorrect Username/Password Combination';
                }
            } else { // if username doesn't exists in the database
                echo 'Entered username isn\'t registered';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Error while preparing sql query';
        }
    }

?>
```

Here's my relevant javascript code

```
let loginForm = document.querySelector('.login-form');
let usernameField = document.getElementById('username-field');
let passwordField = document.getElementById('password-field');

// submit login form to server using ajax
function ajaxFormSubmit() {
    'use strict';
    let ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = 'admin login.php';

    // login form submitted on server successfully
    ajaxRequest.onload = function () {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4 && ajaxRequest.status === 200) {
            console.log(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            displayInfoMessage(ajaxRequest.responseText, 'success');
        }
    };

    // error while login form submission on server
    ajaxRequest.onerror = function () {
        if (ajaxRequest.status !== 200) {
            console.log(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            displayInfoMessage(ajaxRequest.responseText, 'error');
        }
    };

    ajaxRequest.open('POST', url, true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajaxRequest.send(new FormData(loginForm));
}

function validateForm(e) {
    'use strict';

    // prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    if (anyEmptyField()) {
        displayInfoMessage('Please fill all the empty fields', 'error');
        highLightEmptyFields();
        //return false;
        return;
    }

    // check if username is in right format
    if (!(regexTester(/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/g, usernameField.value))) {
        displayInfoMessage('Username not valid', 'error');
        highLightTextField(usernameField);
        //return false;
        return;
    }

    // check if username is atleast 3 characters long
    if (usernameField.value.length < 3) {
        displayInfoMessage('Username should contain atleast 3 characters', 'error');
        highLightTextField(usernameField);
        //return false;
        return;
    }

    // check if password is in right format
    if (!(regexTester(/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/g, passwordField.value))) {
        displayInfoMessage('Password not valid', 'error');
        highLightTextField(passwordField);
        //return false;
        return;
    }

    // check if password is atleast 6 characters long
    if (passwordField.value.length < 6) {
        displayInfoMessage('Password should contain atleast 6 characters', 'error');
        highLightTextField(passwordField);
        //return false;
        return;
    }

    //return true;
    // submit form information to server via ajax
    ajaxFormSubmit();
}

// add submit event listener on login form
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', validateForm);
```

Comment: I suggest using Ajax. This will allow you to send your form data towards your PHP file and get the result back without reloading the page. Based on the result, you can call any JS function you want or redirect the user somewhere with JS. Unfortunetely I can't turn this into an answer because you're not showing your PHP code or HTML form.

Comment: @icecub i have included my web page code in my question.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason why you want to use jQuery slim and not the regular jQuery library? Problem is that jQuery slim doesn't include ajax and doing this in native javascript is a lot more challenging.

Comment: actually i have included JQuery only for bootstrap, otherwise i am using only native javascript. If you can show me how to do it in native javascript, that would really help me learn. But if that takes too much of your time, go ahead and use jQuery :)

Comment: I'll see what I can do. Will take some time. Been a while since I did this in native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `<head></head>` elements of your HTML structure, add the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Wait for the document to load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // Add event listener to form submit
    document.querySelector(".login-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        // Prevent the form from being submitted
        e.preventDefault();

        // Perform displayErrorBlock() function
        validateForm();

        // Create native XMLHttpRequest object
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Set POST request header leaving second parameter empty because PHP
        // code is in the same file.
        xhr.open('POST', '');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            // Everything was ok, handle response
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                // Succesful login. Redirect user
                if(xhr.responseText === 'succes'){
                    window.location.replace("https://your_website.com/admin dashboard.php");
                }
                // Wrong username / password
                else if(xhr.responseText === 'errorUserPass'){
                    displayErrorBlock("Incorrect Username/Password");
                }
                // User doesn't exist
                else if(xhr.responseText === 'errorNotRegistered'){
                    displayErrorBlock("Entered Username isn't registered");
                }
                // Something else was returned by PHP
                else {
                    displayErrorBlock("Unknown error: "+ xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
            // Request failed, alert error
            else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(new FormData(document.querySelector(".login-form")));
    });
});
</script>
```

I've commented on most lines to explain what they do. Next you'll have to change your form to:

```
<form class="login-form" method="post" action="">
```

As we've created a custom event handler on the form, everything is controlled from there. So it's no longer needed to do this in your HTML structure.

Lastly you'll need to change your PHP code in such a way that it returns the correct responses:

Replace: `header('Location:admin dashboard.php');` with `echo 'succes';`
Replace: `echo '<script>displayErrorBlock("Incorrect Username/Password")</script>';` with `echo 'errorUserPass';`
Replace: `echo '<script>displayErrorBlock("Entered Username isn\'t registered")</script>';` with `echo 'errorNotRegistered';`

As I said in the comments, it's been a while since I did this in native JS. I was unable to actually test this code, so let me know if something is wrong. Or at least it should help you into the right direction.

Comment: You have no idea how much i appreciate you taking out the time to do this for me. This certainly showed me how to do this using native javascript. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nick It's in the middle of the night here, so unfortunetely I rly have to go to bed now. I'm not entirely sure what's going on, but you can replace `if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])) {` with `if(!empty($_POST['username-field']) && !empty($_POST['password-field'])) {`. Hopefully that fixes the other issue as well

Comment: @Nick Oh, and you might want to test removing this line: `ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`. I'm not entirely sure if that messes with the FormData Object.

Comment: @Nick Hmm. In that case all I can think of is a Teamviewer session. That way I can actually see your environment for myself and help you out live. Let me know if you're interested in that

Comment: I have made it work by separating the php code from html code. I have included the php code in a separate file and removed the `if condition` that wasn't evaluating to true.

Comment: @Nick Awesome! Glad you've figured something out :)